# How to remove intersecting String[] arrays from a nested ArrayList of String arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Lets say i have an
`ArrayList<ArrayList<String[]>>` variable named `ListToProcess` where in each arrayList i have the following `ArrayLists of String[]`:

```
    String[] arr1 = {"1","2","3"};
    String[] arr2 = {"7","5","3"};
    String[] arr3 = {"8","2","6"};
    String[] arr4 = {"0","4","9"};
```

`ArrayList<String[]> arrString1` contains `arr1` and `arr2` and `ArrayList<String[]> arrString1` constains `arr3` and `arr4`
I want to process `ListToProcess` in such a way that removes `arr2` & `arr3` since intersect with `arr1`(or keep `arr2`and remove `arr1` and `arr3`...) from it.
I try through flattening `ListToProcess` to a `List<String[]>` and remove intersecting elements through the below method `removeIntersectingArrays`

```
    List<String[]> flatList =
            partitionsOfClustersIds.stream()
                    .flatMap(ListToProcess::stream)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    ArrayList<String[]> flattenedArrayElements=  new ArrayList<String[]>(flatList);
    flattenedArrayElements= removeIntersectingArrays(flattenedArrayElements);
```

The `removeIntersectingArrays` method is the following :

```
Public static ArrayList<String[]> removeIntersectingArrays(ArrayList<String[]> totalArrays) {
        List<Integer> idx = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < totalArrays.size(); i++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < totalArrays.size(); j++) {
                String[] tmpArr = totalArrays.get(j);
                if (Arrays.stream(totalArrays.get(i)).distinct().filter(x -> Arrays.stream(tmpArr).anyMatch(y -> y.equals(x))).toArray().length != 0) {

                    idx.add(j);
                }
            }
        Collections.reverse(idx);
        for (int k : idx)
            totalArrays.remove(k); // this line raises an indexOutOfBound exception
        return totalArrays;
    }
```

But i get and `indexOutOfBound` error, any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: By “intersect,” do you mean “has at least one element in common”?

Comment: yes that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't use concrete implementation** (like `ArrayList`) **instead of abstractions** (like `List`) when it doesn't buy you anything. And that is often the case, the only exception is when you need to be able to invoke methods that are not defined in the `List` interface and only accessible through `ArrayList class` like `ensureCapacity()` or `trimToSize()`.

Side note:

- `Collectors.toList()` uses `ArrayList` as implementation of the `List` interface by default;
- whenever you need a **specific implementation** use of `Collector.toCollection()`.

The time complexity of the `removeIntersectingArrays()` method is reduced by maintaining a `HashSet` which stores strings from all the arrays that are encountered before. And every array has to be checked against this set.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<String[]>> list= List.of(
                List.of(new String[]{"1","2","3"},
                        new String[]{"7","5","3"}),
                List.of(new String[]{"8","2","6"},
                        new String[]{"0","4","9"})
        );

        List<String[]> flatList = flatten(list);

        for (String[] arr: removeIntersectingArrays(flatList)) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }
    }
```

```
    public static List<String[]> flatten(List<List<String[]>> source) {
        return source.stream()
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

```
    public static List<String[]> removeIntersectingArrays(List<String[]> source) {
        List<String[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<String> seen = new HashSet<>();
        for (String[] arr: source) {
            boolean notSeenPreviously = true;
            for (String next: arr) {
                if (seen.contains(next)) {
                    notSeenPreviously = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (notSeenPreviously) {
                result.add(arr);
                Collections.addAll(seen, arr);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

**output** (`arr2` & `arr3` are removed)

```
[1, 2, 3]
[0, 4, 9]
```

Comment: @MarcusLemonis your issue was in the second for loop, that will work: `for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) { idx.add(i); }`

Comment: @MarcusLemonis "seemed overly complicated" - that's a delusion.  your implementation of the method `removeIntersectingArrays()` is difficult to debug because it violates [**the single responsibility principle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) (it does multiple things).

Comment: @MarcusLemonis also, please note that mutation of the collection that is passed to the method as an argument isn't considered to be good practice.

Comment: @MarcusLemonis "seemed overly complicated" - I've proved that the code I've provided performs better and it also meets with best practices, if something remains unclear it's  OK, then just ask me.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that removing duplicates from the list of indexes of elements to remove solved it: so doing:

```
        ...
        // remove duplicates
        List<Integer> idxWithoutDuplicates = new ArrayList<>(
                new LinkedHashSet<>(idx));
        Collections.reverse(idxWithoutDuplicates); ...
```

Solved my issue.

UPDATE : or other solution is : to check whether the index is already added to `idx` array above through for example this liner :

```
...
if (!Arrays.asList(idx).contains(j))
    idx.add(j);...
```

Comment: But you didn't find out the reason `why you a having the duplicates at the first place`.  And take a look at this line `new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(idx))` - it works only by chance because Set `doesn't guarantee the order`, but you imply that the initial order will be preserved. Unfortunately, your solution is still broken.

Comment: if you changed the nested loop - that eliminates the cause of the problem, the wouldn't be any duplicates. hence no need to wrap the list with a LinkedHashSet ;)

Comment: i can now assure you that this solution `for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {` didn't work for me as you said it would.

Comment: what kind of issue? index `i` will never get repeated

Comment: `this for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {.. throwed same exception as before so didn't work` -  what was the input? if you are adding the index `i` there must be no duplicated in the `idx list` and no reason for IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Statements inside the nested `for-loop` have to be written exactly as I've told before. The index of the array that is being examined is denoted by `i` variable. If the condition was triggered no need to iterate further, control must go out of the nested loop. Obviously there must be `break` statement for this purpose, just add it directly after `idx.add(i)` (similar data flow you can see in my answer). That will give a single result [0,1] for the input [0,1], [0,2], [1,2].

Comment: These changes will resolve the most important issues with your code instead of disguising them

Comment: Are you still going to insist that the quality of my answer and suggestions is unsatisfactory?

Comment: The difference is in the `number of comparisons`, that are done per every element in each array. Only one action is required per one array element if all previously encountered strings are stored in a HashSet - `set.contains()`. Otherwise, each element of the array that is being checked has to be compared with every element of every previously encountered array (that is what's happening inside your stream-based condition).

Comment: examine the data flow in this stream: `Arrays.stream(totalArrays.get(i)).distinct().filter(x -> Arrays.stream(tmpArr).anyMatch(y -> y.equals(x))).toArray().length != 0`. How many times method `equals()` will be invoked for every of the array at index `i` ?

Comment: In my solution it's an equivalent of ` if (seen.contains(next)) ` which performs in a constant time `O(1)`

Comment: almost every solution, written by someone else requires efforts to comprehend, that's normal. `boolean flag` is a necessary part, no way to remove it.